# How to tell Emacs to keep indentation in algorithmic environment?

Tags: latex, indentation, auctex

I frequently find myself typesetting algorithms, and I choose the `algorithmicx`/`algpseudocode` package for that. I like the package, it is simple to use and has everything I typically need.

The problem (a big inconvenience, actually) is that Emacs (AUCTeX) destroys the indentation inside the `algorithmic` environment, and that renders the algorithms much harder to read in the LaTeX source.

Is there any (simple) way to tell Emacs to keep the contents of the `algorithmic` environment with their original indentation while still performing the highlighting of the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should customize the variable `LaTeX-indent-environment-list` to add an entry for `algorithmic` to be `current-indentation`.  I.e. `INS` insert new entry, complete with `algorithmic` for the `Environment:` and specify `current-indentation` for `Function:`.   See the `Indenting` section of the AuCTeX info page for more detail.

Here is a screenshoot of how such customizations look like in the customize interface

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked, but only after I changed the valued of the «Function» field to `current-indentation`, like it is for the `verbatim` environment.

Comment: Thanks for checking this - I wrote `current-indentation` first and then changed it to ignore, but forgot to retest.  Answer updated.

Comment: @AndrewSwann  How can I specify `current-indentation` or change the `«Function» field`?

Comment: @alper I have now added an image.  Does that help?

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thanks I have added a entry as `Environmet: algorithmic Function: current-indentation` but it did not make any indent change :-( I have added it as a question to explain my question https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/69996/18414