# How can I align indents for condition statements in AucTex algorithm section?

Tags: latex, auctex, tabs, align

If possible, I want to align condition statements like: `\If`, `\Else`, `\For` statements in between `\begin{algorithmic} ... \end{algorithmic}` section.

example:

```tex
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\For{a for statement}                | for a for stament
    \If{some coding}                 |     if some coding    
        \State do something          |         do something  
    \EndIf                           |
\EndFor                              | 
\If{some coding}                     | if some coding
    \State do something              |      do something  
\EndIf 
\end{algorithmic}
```

---

Following example `latex` code taken from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/615852/127048.
When I select all lines in the buffer an press (`TAB indent-for-tab-command`) it aligns all if else statements in the same vertical line. In `python-mode` `indent-for-tab-command` successfully align indents.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Main D Algorithm}\label{alg:cap}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\For{a for statement}
    \If{some coding}
    \State do something
    \ElsIf{another condition}
        \For{some condition}
            \If{another statement}
                \State do something
            \EndIf
        \EndFor
    \ElsIf{problem is here}
        \State whatever
    \EndIf
\EndFor
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

After `TAB indent-for-tab-command` the buffer is converted into:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Main D Algorithm}\label{alg:cap}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \For{a for statement}
    \If{some coding}
    \State do something
    \ElsIf{another condition}
    \For{some condition}
    \If{another statement}
    \State do something
    \EndIf
    \EndFor
    \ElsIf{problem is here}
    \State whatever
    \EndIf
    \EndFor
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35908/how-to-tell-emacs-to-keep-indentation-in-algorithmic-environment help?

Comment: @NickD I have applied the answer on the link, but it does not make any indent changes. add entry as `Environmet: algorithmic Function: current-indentation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your init file:

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'latex
    (add-to-list 'LaTeX-indent-environment-list '("algorithmic" current-indentation)))
```

That's the equivalent of the customization, but maybe you got the customization wrong somehow.

You should check the value of `LaTeX-indent-environment-list` and make sure that there *is* an `algorithmic` entry in it:

```
Value:
(("algorithmic" current-indentation)
 ("verbatim" current-indentation)
 ("verbatim*" current-indentation)
 ("filecontents" current-indentation)
 ("filecontents*" current-indentation)
 ("tabular" LaTeX-indent-tabular)
 ("tabular*" LaTeX-indent-tabular)
 ("align" LaTeX-indent-tabular)
 ("align*" LaTeX-indent-tabular)
 ("array" LaTeX-indent-tabular)
 ("eqnarray" LaTeX-indent-tabular)
 ("eqnarray*" LaTeX-indent-tabular)
 ("displaymath")
 ("equation")
 ("equation*")
 ("picture")
 ("tabbing"))
```

You should also check that `LaTeX-indent-environment-check` is set to `t`. That is the default, but you never know.
In fact, you should probably do both of these checks in your current setup and maybe that will point out what you did wrong in the customization.

After restarting Emacs and opening the file, the indentation of the contents of an `algorithmic` environment should not be affected by TAB.

I have a feeling that even though this answers the current question, it is not going to be satisfactory in the long run, but I'll let you experiment and ask more questions about it later.

Comment: `TAB` affect is removed. I think I have to align inner `If` indents manually, right? It wouldn't add 4 space before the inner `If`s like its done in python. For example, If i provide the converted version (second version algorithm on my question), and press TAB, the indent alignment wouldn't be done automatically

Comment: @alper, if you do not have imposed constraints, you can use the package ```algorithm2e``` where TAB works when typing. If forced to use ```algorithm```, note that other editors (TeXShop, Vim, Vscode) can be used, TAB works when typing.

Comment: @Ian I have tried `algorithm2e ` but when I press `TAB` all the lines moved into same indent level like I asked on my question

Comment: @alper, take care, ```algorithm2e``` has a different syntax - you have an ```algorithm2e.pdf``` documentation in your LaTeX installation. One more note: your observed behaviour in the second version algorithm snippet is as requested by the package ```algorithm``` and is imposed by the style file ```algorithm.el``` in your ```auctex/style``` folder.

Comment: @Ian sorry I didn't get it. As I understand if I use `algorithmic` environment , indent spaces alignment would not be applied so instead I have to use `algorithm2e`?

Comment: @alper, do not mix with ```algorithmic```. Only ```algorithm2e``` should be in the preamble of your file.

Comment: @alper, yes, use only ```\usepackage{algorithm2e}``` and comment other lines containing ```algpseudocode```. If nothing works, try to edit that environment in TeXShop, it is by default installed by LaTeX.

Comment: @Ian it took a lot of digging but I find a alternative solution using latexinden.pl along with apheleia, its not perfectly combined but it works somehow

Answer (score 1):

AUCTeX is able to indent conditionals better with [this change](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/commit/?id=0ce906cfc7a33a0be50180a6344ddfdfe0d89cb7).  At the same time, the code in `algpseudocode.el` [was adjusted](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/commit/?id=4bcda2d50c5b3752a0b292c006f7d90b099a67a7) to take advantage of this feature.

If I take your example, indent the line with `\caption` and `\begin{algorithmic}[1]` manually by hitting <kbd>TAB</kbd>, then put point before `\For` and hit <kbd>M-q</kbd>, I get this:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Main D Algorithm}\label{alg:cap}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \For{a for statement}
      \If{some coding}
        \State do something
      \ElsIf{another condition}
        \For{some condition}
          \If{another statement}
            \State do something
          \EndIf
        \EndFor
      \ElsIf{problem is here}
        \State whatever
      \EndIf
    \EndFor
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Just wait for next AUCTeX release from ELPA which should happen soon, and you don't need to rely on external tools anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using https://github.com/raxod502/apheleia and
[latexindent.pl](https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl) together.

*localSettings.yaml* for `latexindent.pl` [its issue](https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl/issues/324#issuecomment-1012800645):

```yaml
defaultIndent: "    "
specialBeginEnd:
  If:
    begin: '\\If'
    middle: '\\ElsIf'
    end: '\\EndIf'
    lookForThis: 1
  specialBeforeCommand: 1
```

Installing `latexindent.pl`:

```
mkdir ~/bin && cd ~/bin
git clone https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl.git
chmod +x latexindent.pl/latexindent.pl
export PATH=~/bin:$PATH
```

**latexindent**:  should be executable and its path exist in `PATH`

```bash
#!/bin/bash
cp $HOME/localSettings.yaml .
~/bin/latexindent.pl/latexindent.pl -l $1
```

---

`apheleia` will run `latexindent` automatically when a `.tex` file is opened.